# Get All Pages with an Apollo Query

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo

Suppose I have 500 rows in my database. I want to get 100 pages of 50 rows. Here is an example of a `fetchMore` request.

```
const fetchNextPage = (props) => {
  props.Query.fetchMore({
    query: gql(getRows),
    variables: {
      skip: props.Query.rows.length,
    },
    updateQuery: (previousResult, next) => {
      return {
        ...previousResult,
        rows: [...previousResult.rows, ...next.fetchMoreResult.rows],
      };
    },
  });
}
```

What I'm unsure about is...

1. How I can fetch all pages without additional user action?
2. Since I know the total number of needed pages how can I send them in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do that with one operation. Using `aliases` you can request the same field multiple times with different arguments.

Here is the official [explanation about aliases](http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#aliases).

In your case it would be something similar to:

```
  query GetAllPages {
      page1rows: rows(skip: 0, limit: 50) { # "skip" and "limit" are just regular variable names
          #...rowFields
      }
      page2rows: rows(skip: 50, limit: 50) {
          #...rowFields
      }
      #... etc.
  }
```

In this example `page1rows` and `page2rows` are aliases for the `rows` field. You can choose other aliases.

Note that `skip` and `limit` are nothing special, they are plain variables and their use depends on the schema and resolvers on the server. I see in your code you use `skip`, if you **know** you'll always get 50 rows then `limit` is redundant.

The response should be something like:

```
{
  "data": {
    "page1rows": [
      //... rows
    ],
    "page2rows": [
      //... rows
    ],
    //... etc.
  }
}
```

That way works without additional user action, you get all pages at once and there's no need to use `fetchMore`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer Tal. One problem I have is the response payload is too large for one query. That's why paging the response.

Comment: But how to do it in vue-apollo? I always getting this error message: `Missing myQuery attribute on result`.